# Entity Framework Error when no records are returned

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

.Net Framework 4 | SQL Server 2008 | Entity Framework 6

I am calling a function import that calls a stored procedure and creates a complex object.  In some cases the result is 0 records.  It seems that if you have this case all the columns in the complex object must be set to allow nulls.  I don't want to do that because, if there were records, non of the columns would be null.  This is causing me to have to check for nulls on all of these fields instead of just checking if the returned list has any rows.

Am I doing something wrong or is that just the way EF is set up?

UPDATE:

I'm not really sure what code you want.  It's a simple SELECT statement. The stored procedure call is through a regular Function Import.  Here's how I am calling that:

```
// Get the district entity
List<SchoolCollectionSummary_Result>  summaries =
    context.GetSchoolCollectionSummary(
    schoolYear.SchoolYearId, districtOrganizationId,
schoolOrganizationId).ToList();
```

SchoolCollectionSummary_Result is a complex type (entity) based on the stored procedure.

As soon as I enumerate it the error occurs:

```
{"The 'SchoolCollectionId' property on 'SchoolCollectionSummary_Result' could not be set to a 'null' value. You must set this property to a non-null value of type 'System.Int32'. "}
```

I set all the fields "allow null = false" because the database fields are set to NOT NULL.

Thanks.

UPDATE

Thanks for asking for the SQL.  When looking through it I noticed there's a LEFT JOIN which was the cause of my problems...

Comment: Can you post some code that shows how you are executing the stored proc and returning the result.

Comment: Yes, you are doing something wrong. Without any example code, no one would possibly gues what, though.

Comment: Please see my update in the post.

Comment: Can you please post what the StoredProc returns, as in SQL terms as well as set up of the entity class in C#?

Comment: The error indicates that the `SchoolCollectionSummary_Result` class has the `int SchoolCollectionId` field, however, the actual column in the database allows null values and of course EF doesn't like this mismatch. Either change the class member to `int? SchoolCollectionId` or fix your database schema.